# How To Merge Two Table into one output data

Tags: sql-server, union

I have two tables with similar information:
`1st Table For Estimation Data :`

```
EstChargeCode | EstAmount
------------- | -------------
CNFS0001      | 43,250,000.00
CNIH0001      | 0.00
CNIH0001      | 2,625,000.00
CNIP0001      | 4,500,000.00
CNIP0005      | 2,250,000.00
CNOH0001      | 20,484,690.00
CNOP0001      | 0.00
```

`2nd Table for Actual Data :`

```
ActChargeCode | ActAmount
------------- | -------------
CNFS0001      | 39,950,000.00
CNIH0001      | 1,300,000.00
CNIH0001      | 950,000.00
CNIH0001      | -950,000.00
CNIH0001      | 950,000.00
CNIP0001      | 4,500,000.00
CNIP0005      | 2,250,005.00
CNOH0001      | 20,484,690.00
CNOP0001      | 3,300,000.00
```

if using **Union All** to merge the table from above then the result like this

```
ChargeCode | EstAmount     | ActAmount
---------- | ------------- | -------------
CNFS0001   | 43,250,000.00 | -------------  
CNIH0001   | 0.00          | -------------
CNIH0001   | 2,625,000.00  | -------------  
CNIP0001   | 4,500,000.00  | -------------
CNIP0005   | 2,250,000.00  | -------------
CNOH0001   | 20,484,690.00 | -------------
CNOP0001   | 0.00          | -------------
CNFS0001   | ------------- | 39,950,000.00
CNIH0001   | ------------- | 1,300,000.00
CNIH0001   | ------------- | 950,000.00
CNIH0001   | ------------- | -950,000.00
CNIH0001   | ------------- | 950,000.00
CNIP0001   | ------------- | 4,500,000.00
CNIP0005   | ------------- | 2,250,005.00
CNOH0001   | ------------- | 20,484,690.00
CNOP0001   | ------------- | 3,300,000.00
```

I need to group both data into single result data like this

```
ChargeCode | EstAmount     | ActAmount
---------- | ------------- | -------------
CNFS0001   | 43,250,000.00 | 39,950,000.00
CNIH0001   | 0.00          | 1,300,000.00
CNIH0001   | 0.00          | 950,000.00
CNIH0001   | 0.00          | -950,000.00
CNIH0001   | 0.00          | 950,000.00
CNIH0001   | 2,625,000.00  | 0.00
CNIP0001   | 4,500,000.00  | 4,500,000.00
CNIP0005   | 2,250,000.00  | 2,250,005.00
CNOH0001   | 20,484,690.00 | 20,484,690.00
CNOP0001   | 0.00          | 3,300,000.00
```

I don't know how handle this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need just to join your tables with `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 1):

you can use code like below

```
  select isnull(EstChargeCode ,ActChargeCode ) as ChargeCode ,isnull(EstAmount,0) as 
    EstAmount , isnull(ActAmount,0) as ActAmount from Estimation full join Actual 
    on Estimation.EstChargeCode =Actual.ActChargeCode
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.EstChargeCode as ChargeCode , 
       a.EstAmount, 
       b.ActAmount 
from Estimation_Data as a 
LEFT JOIN Actual_Data as b 
ON a.ActChargeCode =b.ActChargeCode
```

Comment: @ankit what is wrong in my answer?check your answer there are no such a ActChargeCode column in Estimation_Data  table

Comment: Really? `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: @Sami Could be valid - we have no idea whether rows are guaranteed to exist in either table. Estimates could have been made with no actual amounts yet. Actual amounts could be known without an estimate - OP didn't specify.. Without guesswork the only valid option would be full outer join (like Hassan's answer).

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Code only answers are low quality and subject to deletion, there should always be at least one or two sentences (optimally a paragraph) about what question you are addressing, conditions, pitfalls, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOIN` to achieve the result:

```
SELECT t2.ActAmount  ChargeCode ,nvl(t1.EstAmount,0.0) EstAmount, nvl(t2.ActAmount,0.0) ActAmount
FROM <Estimation Data table> t1
RIGHT OUTER JOIN <Actual Data> t2 ON t1.EstChargeCode = t2.ActChargeCode ;
```

For more clarification, there is an explanation here:
[What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join)

Comment: Use JOIN instead of Union

Answer (score 0):

You use `INNER JOIN` like:

```
SELECT T1.EstChargeCode AS EstChargeCode,
       T1.EstAmount AS EstAmount1,
       T2.EstAmount AS EstAmount2
FROM Table1 T1 INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.EstChargeCode = T2.ActChargeCode;
```